# Parsing using SAXParserFactory with multiple threads

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax, saxparser

I have to parse a given xml file using SAX parser.
This xml file contains data which would be parsed using multiple default handlers.
First parser will parse some information, second will parse some other information and so on... from the same file.

The above process may be running in multiple threads i.e. multiple xml files and multiple parsers per xml file.

So, if i have 5 xml files and 5 handlers. Then there would be 5*5 = 25 processes running parallely.

Now, `SAXParserFactory` is not thread safe.

***So, do i have to do the following for each thread ?***

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
```

OR can i use same parser object for a given xml for all the handlers in which case i will have 5 parsers (one per xml).
But i am not sure if that would work.

Comment: Is SAX parser a much for your project? Are you aware that it is very hard to code in SAX? Do you know what XPath can do you?

Comment: We use SAX Parser for now. I have implemented the complete parser with SAX but now i need to extend it to be used with multiple threads and hence the question! I have not used XPath but i do know about it (Very basic though). Do you have an idea about the question i asked? Would be of great help if you can provide your expetise here. Will learn XPath going forward

Comment: Also, the xml output will be created as a result of a command and can vary. So, path is not constant here.